# Draw coordinate in circumference of circle

Tags: javascript, geometry

I am trying to calculating new coordinate from the centre of the circle. So I already searched and got a formula like this:

```
x = r cos(ϴ)
y = r sin(ϴ)
```

my code works, but the results are not what I expected

```
function process()
{
    //
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('myx').value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('myy').value);
    var radius = parseInt(document.getElementById('radius').value);

    var mytext =  document.getElementById('result');

    for( var i=0;i<360;i+=45){
        var new_x = x + radius*Math.cos(toDegrees(i));
        var new_y = y + radius*Math.sin(toDegrees(i));

        mytext.innerHTML += " radius = "+radius+" , angle="+i+"<br/>";
        mytext.innerHTML += " old ("+x+", "+y+") ";
        mytext.innerHTML += " | ("+new_x+", "+new_y+") <br/><br/>";
    }
}

function toDegrees (angle) {
    return angle * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function toRadians (angle) {
    return angle * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

the result : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN0Bp.png)

in 90 degrees should be : (0, -50)

Is the formula wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.cos()` takes radians as parameter ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos)), but you use degrees. Use `toRadians(angle)` method you already have in your code:

```
var new_x = x + radius*Math.cos(toRadius(i));
var new_y = y + radius*Math.sin(toRadius(i));
```

**Edit:** It will not return `0` (thanks number PI for being such an irrational number), but `3.061616997868383e-15` as X coordinate value in 90 degrees. Well, that `e` thing, stands for `x10^` scientifically. Hence, `3.061616997868383e-15` is simply `3.061616997868383 x 10^-15` which is extremely small. To see `0` exactly, have a look at [number methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp) and choose the best fit precision (For instance, `3.061616997868383e-15.toFixed(4)` results in `0.0000`)

Comment: Thanks! , my mistake .... example 90 angle , the result is `(3.061616997868383e-15, 50)` . I don't see (e-15)

Comment: Added an edit section in the answer, if not seeing the exact zero (`0`) is your point.

Answer (score 0):

Like Vahdet says on that answer, `Math.cos()` takes radians and not degrees.

You can simplify your code and make it take user input instead of looping through fixed values, besides being simpler it should be more useful.

```js
let angleContainer = document.getElementById('angle');
let radiusContainer = document.getElementById('radius');

let x = document.getElementById('x');
let y = document.getElementById('y');

angleContainer.addEventListener('input', () => {
    updateDom(
        parseInt(angleContainer.value),
        parseInt(radiusContainer.value),
        x, y)
});

radiusContainer.addEventListener('input', () => {
    updateDom(
        parseInt(angleContainer.value),
        parseInt(radiusContainer.value),
        x, y)
});

function updateDom(angle, radius, x, y) {
    x.innerText = radius * Math.cos(toRadians(angle));
    y.innerText = radius * Math.sin(toRadians(angle));
}

function toRadians(angle) {
    return angle * Math.PI / 180;
}

updateDom(
    parseInt(angleContainer.value),
    parseInt(radiusContainer.value),
    x, y);
```

```css
#calculator {
    background: #00816A;
    padding: 2em;
}

#calculator > h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

#radius-input, #angle-input {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

#x-container, #y-container {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#x, #y {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">

    <h1>Coordinates calculator</h1>

    <div id="radius-input">
        <label for="radius">Radius:</label>
        <input id="radius" type="number" value="1">
    </div>

    <div id="angle-input">
        <label for="angle">Angle (deg):</label>
        <input type="number" id="angle" value="45">
    </div>

    <div id="outputs">
        <div id="x-container">X: <span id="x"></span></div>
        <div id="y-container">Y: <span id="y"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```